change wordpress address from blog.site.com to site.com/blog
I have a site on a server (ubuntu/nginx) with site.com address and I installed a wordpress on another server with blog.site.com address. Now i want to show blog with site.com/blog
on First server, I added this location to nginx config
location /blog {
        proxy_pass https://blog.site.com/;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}

it works. but when i click on a post it load with blog.site.com/post-name
I changed home address on wordpress admin panel to
site.com/blog

but when I click on a post it call
site.com/blogpost-name

How can I fix it?

It seems you need to update both your site's WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). If you've already updated these in the WordPress admin panel, ensure your nginx configuration on site.com server includes the correct location block for /blog. Here's an example:

location /blog {
alias /path/to/your/wordpress;
index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

location ~ .php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}

}
Replace /path/to/your/wordpress with the actual file system path to your WordPress installation, and ensure the fastcgi_pass directive points to the correct PHP socket file for your setup.
Additionally, you may need to update your WordPress database to reflect the new URL structure, particularly for posts, pages, and attachments URLs. You can use a plugin or a SQL query to change blog.site.com to site.com/blog in the database.
Remember to back up your site before making changes to the configuration or database.

@Coder I installed wordpress on second server. can i use this on first server? location /blog { alias /path/to/your/wordpress; index index.php; try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
